# PHP Striping/Exporting single strings from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, like this:

```
)array (
  'date' => '2015-12-10T00:16:58+0000',
  'from' =>
  array (
    'name' => 'Joe Bloggs',
    'user_id' => 3220562,
  ),
  'message' => ':ip=1.1.1.1',
)
```

And here's my code:

```
$string = var_export($h, true);
echo $string;
```

And finally, here's what I would like to achieve:
I would like to export single strings from the array (for example I want to export 'message', and then I would get an output of ":ip=1.1.1.1").

I have tried things like $h['message'] and this doesn't work, so I'm just wondering what's the easiest / cleanest way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$h["message"]` works. See [eval.in](https://eval.in/483000)

Comment: in your first line, why is there bracket before array ?? is this a 2d array?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice that.. it's not the first array.

Comment: @rockmyalgorithm that works for $h ['message'] but it doesn't work for the name string. https://eval.in/483004

Comment: the `name` is inside the array of array, so to access, you would need like this, `$h["from"]["name"]`

Comment: @user156235, read Andrew's comment with [working example](https://eval.in/483010)